# Receiving ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Blazor (WA) application when trying to inject AuthenticationStateProvider. How can I resolve this?

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have one line on MainLayout.razor

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider;
```

that is intended to let me access `authState.User`. I was prompted to add a SSL certificate when I first created the project and if I remove the above line the application loads up as expected (although still with a not-secure warning). When the above line is included, the site starts to load and then throws an error in the console with the message in the title.

I followed the Microsoft docs and installed the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization**  nuget package and added it to my imports file. I also added the following to my program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
```

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to inject Task<AuthenticationStateProvider> rather than just the object

Comment: Why are you not using the cascaded  `[CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }`?